Trouble triggering OnWebResourceResponseReceived in WebView4Delphi's PopupBrowser Demo?
I'm trying to use the PopupBrowser Demo of WebView4Delphi. In the OnNewWindowRequested event of mainform.WVBrower1, I'm listening and creating a new child window:
procedure TMainForm.WVBrowser1NewWindowRequested(Sender: TObject;
  const aWebView: ICoreWebView2;
  const aArgs: ICoreWebView2NewWindowRequestedEventArgs);
var
  TempChildForm: TChildForm;
begin
  TempChildForm := TChildForm.Create(self, aArgs);
  TempChildForm.Show;
end;

And I want to listen to data in ChildForm.WVBrower1's OnWebResourceResponseReceived, so I added a listening filter in ChildForm.WVBrower1. The code is as follows:
procedure TChildForm.WVBrowser1AfterCreated(Sender: TObject);
begin
  if assigned(FArgs) and assigned(FDeferral) then
    try
      FArgs.NewWindow := WVBrowser1.CoreWebView2.BaseIntf;
      FArgs.Handled   := True;
      FDeferral.Complete;
    finally
      FreeAndNil(FDeferral);
      FreeAndNil(FArgs);
    end;

// Added code
  WVBrowser1.AddWebResourceRequestedFilterWithRequestSourceKinds('*',
    COREWEBVIEW2_WEB_RESOURCE_CONTEXT_ALL,
    COREWEBVIEW2_WEB_RESOURCE_REQUEST_SOURCE_KINDS_ALL);

  WVWindowParent1.UpdateSize;
end;

However, in ChildForm.WVBrowser1's OnWebResourceRequested, I can listen to data, but the OnWebResourceResponseReceived event cannot be triggered. However, if I change the code as follows, I can trigger the listening. But this only works with the GET method. It doesn't work with the payload-carrying POST method，Because I don't know what the access parameters of the new window are.
procedure TChildForm.WVBrowser1AfterCreated(Sender: TObject);
begin
  if assigned(FArgs) and assigned(FDeferral) then
    try
      FArgs.NewWindow := nil;  // Modification here
      FArgs.Handled   := True;
      FDeferral.Complete;
      
      WVBrowser1.Navigate(EncodeURL(FArgs.URI)); // Directly re-access

    finally
      FreeAndNil(FDeferral);
      FreeAndNil(FArgs);
    end;

// Added code
  WVBrowser1.AddWebResourceRequestedFilterWithRequestSourceKinds('*',
    COREWEBVIEW2_WEB_RESOURCE_CONTEXT_ALL,
    COREWEBVIEW2_WEB_RESOURCE_REQUEST_SOURCE_KINDS_ALL);

  WVWindowParent1.UpdateSize;
end;

I appreciate any help. Thank you!
I want to be able to listen to the OnWebResourceResponseReceived event in the new window created in WebView2's NewWindowRequested.
